# Paginate count(*) query issue

Tags: laravel, optimization, eloquent, query-optimization, laravel-8

- Laravel Version: 8.0
- PHP Version: 7.3.0
- Database Driver & Version:  MySQL 5.7.34

#### Describe the Bug

When I use paginate for pagination the data it call the count( * ) query every time even I pass the column name like count(['id']), and the count( * ) query scan all row in the table.

- Table name is `users` and it has 45 column
- Route

```php
Route::get("users", "UsersController@index");
```

- Controller

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return User::paginate(10 , ['id']);
    }
 }
```

- Call `users` route
- Telescope showing me that two queries

#### Actual result

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4kz1.png]

#### Expected  result

[image: [Expected result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhiA7.png)]

#### Steps To Solution:

[image: [Solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Gn7.png)]

- The following image shows that I had done changes as per our functionality, It will take the first column name from the passed in the paginate method array of $columns params and that query does not scan all columns of the users tables.

#### Final Results:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns0r3.png]

I have tired to solving this issue any other way or idea then please let me know

Comment: are you using ( App\Models\User; ) ?!
what is [id]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not recommended to ever touch the vendor files, you can always just override the functionality inside of your model, you can also pass in the columns to override the `getCountForPagination()` and you can also pass the columns to `simplePaginate()` that doesn't invoke any counting!

**In order to optimize the query to count and paginate, you can do it like this:**

```
//We will call the query on the model
$program = Program::query()->getQuery();

//count the query by specific columns
$thePaginationCount = $program->getCountForPagination(['id']);

//paginate the results using simplePaginate and select the columns we want:
$thePaginatedProgram = $program->simplePaginate(10, ['id', 'name']);

return 'test: '.$thePaginatedProgram;
```

**Will result like this:**

```
select count(`id`) as aggregate from `programs`
select `id`, `name` from `programs` limit 11 offset 0
```

[image]

As you can see it will only load what we specify and its very efficient!

---

### Final Note:

If you just want to paginate without the count, you can always call `Model::simplePaginate($amount, [$columns...])`

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#simple-pagination

Comment: Any ideas for the using paginate() method because paginate method is also supported to give the $column value , 

in this, paginate method we have to pass the  column value then and make support for the first $column param as a count($column[0]) the we can solve it in paginate method

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#multiple-paginator-instances-per-page

Comment: what do you mean, you can already access the models like this `foreach($theprogram as $item){ dd($item); }`

Comment: @NikunjGadhiya if your issue is resolved, kindly mark the answer as complete (using the checkmark) :)